# Noob struggling to tell terminal to install scikit-image 0.16.2 for Pyxelate

Tags: macos, terminal, catalina, python

I'm using macOS Catalina version 10.15.7
I think this should be a very easy install, but apparently not.
At first, I spotted terminal told me I don't have Cython. Ok. I installed it, then it gave me a long ass error command, which I have no idea to solve. I barely know what it meant.
And Pyxelate can't take newest version of scikit-image.
Is that my clang's file isn't match the pip3? If so, how can I fix that? I really have no idea.

```
  13 warnings and 1 error generated.
  4 warnings generated.
  error: Command "clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/usr/local/include -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include -I/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c skimage/restoration/_unwrap_2d.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/skimage/restoration/_unwrap_2d.o -MMD -MF build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/skimage/restoration/_unwrap_2d.o.d" failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for scikit-image

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/34/x6521nrj71sb1tmxtpcxsj4c0000gn/T/pip-install-25qrnc9w/scikit-image_5d68c8ee27804ffa8db02d899fd06b99/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/34/x6521nrj71sb1tmxtpcxsj4c0000gn/T/pip-install-25qrnc9w/scikit-image_5d68c8ee27804ffa8db02d899fd06b99/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/34/x6521nrj71sb1tmxtpcxsj4c0000gn/T/pip-record-hddyaqi4/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.9/scikit-image Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: How (which which command) did you try to install Cython?

Comment: I would use a package manager rather than individual builds. The developers have sorted all this out. General p[ackage managers include Macports and Homebrew, python specific include conda

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I've solved this myself.

I just downgraded to python 3.8 and forced installation by using `--user`.